# AAPT: error: attribute 'android:name' in <application> tag must be a valid Java class name

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio

I am building flutter application. when i try to run the application on to my phone through Android Studio. I get the following error

packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:28: AAPT: error: attribute 'android:name' in  tag must be a valid Java class name.

I have searched online and was not able to resolve it. I have tried changing the application name to "${applicationName}" but nothing works, it switches back to default as seen in the code below. It seems like the AndroidManifest mentioned in the error is the debug one as it has a heading on Debug/AndroidManifest.xml. I have tried the regular Android Manifest to copy the application name but the error still persist. new to flutter and would appreciate step by step help.

```
 <application
    android:name="com.example.flutter_auth.@applicationName"
    android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:extractNativeLibs="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="flutter_auth" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.flutter_auth.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:exported="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

i have change the application name to "$applicationName} and also copied the name from the regular manifest.

Comment: I don't think `@applicationName` is a correct name. It should point to your extended `Application` class. If you haven't implemented it, `android:name` isn't necessary.